# Drupal validation for nested field element

Tags: php, jquery, validation, drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal form for save details, I wrote validation for each element in the form. Following method is using for display errors. Then it automatically highlighted the required fields.

```
form_set_error('field_athletes_male', 'Athletes Male field is required.');
```

My problem is there is nested element names like as follows

```
field_coaching_programme[und][0][field_organisation_delivered_by][und][0][value]
```

Validation message is shown successfully but element is not highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried following code and working as expected

```
form_set_error('field_coaching_programme][und][0][field_organisation_delivered_by', 'Organisation delivered by field is required.');
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer you are looking for may already be in the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7).

Here is the relevant part:

> $name: The name of the form element. If the #parents property of your
>   form element is array('foo', 'bar', 'baz') then you may set an error
>   on 'foo' or 'foo][bar][baz'. Setting an error on 'foo' sets an error
>   for every element where the #parents array starts with 'foo'.

Therefore you should try to do the following:

```
form_set_error("field_coaching_programme][field_organisation_delivered_by", t("Error Message"))
```